# Name a column in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I came up with following code that adds number of columns based on user input in textbox1, but how to add names to these columns? (Columns added should have names like, A1,A2,A3.......on the top most row)

```
Dim t As Integer
t = Val(TextBox1.Text)
For i = 1 To t
    Form2.DataGridView1.ColumnCount = i
Next
```

Also can we freeze specific cells in a datagridview i.e. cells which user cannot edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name = String.Format("A{0}", i)
```

Once you have access to Columns(i) you can view available properties from the intellisense

```
DataGridView1.Columns(0).Frozen = True;
```

Comment: Array in VB.net are denoted as (i) not [i]

Comment: Thats ok, +1 your answer is correct as far as headers go, It sounds like he wants to freeze individual cells not rows or columns.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. I wish I could mark 2 answers as "accepted". Combination of your answer and Mark Hall's answer solved my problem.

Comment: @codingbiz:This worked on my sample, but for my main project it is throwing following exeption: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index. is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: make sure `t` is not greater than the number of columns on your grid. Actually your `i` should start from `0` e.g. `For i = 0 to t-1`

Comment: @mrn try changing `DataGridView1.Columns(i).Name` to `DataGridView1.Columns(i-1).Name`.  Indexes are zero based, you are starting at 1 therefore exeeding the bounds of the array.

Comment: @Codingbiz worth also mentioning the HeaderText property of a DataGridViewColumn. The Name property is only used for the header text when the HeaderText property is not specified, giving a little bit more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

The DataGridView only has methods for freezing Rows or Columns, in order to block editing of a specific cell you can try adding a handler for the CellBeginEdit event then check for the Row and Column of the Cell(s) that you want to prevent editing of then cancel the event.

something like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellBeginEdit
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 And e.RowIndex = 0 Then
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This forum should allow users to mark 2 answers as "accepted". Really thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

```cs
 this.dataGridView1.Columns["StudentId"].ReadOnly = true;
```

from: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/fef91d76-24c5-4b41-84d7-ba133de2d9a7#b2cb53ec-5b15-4385-b086-28a6dc93dfc9